# A @Target-less annotation cannot be applied to a type parameter declaration in Java 19: why not?

Tags: java, language-lawyer, annotation-processing, jls

[Section 9.6.4.1 of the Java Language Specification version 19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.1) lists all declaration contexts in the Java language.  One of those declaration contexts is "[Type parameter declarations of generic classes, interfaces, methods, and constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.1:%7E:text=Type%20parameter%20declarations,annotation.ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER)".

The Java Language Specification version 19 says "[If an annotation of type `java.lang.annotation.Target` is not present on the declaration of an annotation interface `A`, then `A` is applicable in all declaration contexts and in no type contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.1:%7E:text=If%20an%20annotation%20of%20type%20java.lang.annotation.Target%20is%20not%20present%20on%20the%20declaration%20of%20an%20annotation%20interface%20A%2C%20then%20A%20is%20applicable%20in%20all%20declaration%20contexts%20and%20in%20no%20type%20contexts.)"

The [javadocs for `@Target` in Java 19 say](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Target.html) that if I have an annotation class not annotated with `@Target`, my annotation may be used "[as a modifier for any declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Target.html#:%7E:text=If%20an%20%40Target%20meta%2Dannotation%20is%20not%20present%20on%20an%20annotation%20interface%20T%2C%20then%20an%20annotation%20of%20type%20T%20may%20be%20written%20as%20a%20modifier%20for%20any%20declaration.)" (full stop).

In the Java Language Specification version 13, but *not* in 14 and later, the text reads, instead: "[If an annotation of type `java.lang.annotation.Target` is not present on the declaration of an annotation type `T`, then `T` is applicable in all declaration contexts **except type parameter declarations**, and in no type contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.1:%7E:text=If%20an%20annotation%20of%20type%20java.lang.annotation.Target%20is%20not%20present%20on%20the%20declaration%20of%20an%20annotation%20type%20T%2C%20then%20T%20is%20applicable%20in%20all%20declaration%20contexts%20except%20type%20parameter%20declarations%2C%20and%20in%20no%20type%20contexts.)".

The javadocs for `@Target` in Java 13 (but not in 14 and later) read (similarly): "[If an annotation of type `java.lang.annotation.Target` is not present on the declaration of an annotation type `T`, then `T` is applicable in all declaration contexts **except type parameter declarations**, and in no type contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Target.html#:%7E:text=If%20an%20%40Target%20meta%2Dannotation%20is%20not%20present%20on%20an%20annotation%20type%20T%20%2C%20then%20an%20annotation%20of%20type%20T%20may%20be%20written%20as%20a%20modifier%20for%20any%20declaration%20except%20a%20type%20parameter%20declaration.)".

The javadocs for `@Target` in Java 17 finally change (belatedly?) to match the specification (as changed in 14), reading (as they do today in Java 19): "[If an [sic] `@Target` meta-annotation is not present on an annotation interface `T`, then an annotation of type `T` may be written as a modifier for any declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Target.html#:%7E:text=If%20an%20%40Target%20meta%2Dannotation%20is%20not%20present%20on%20an%20annotation%20interface%20T%2C%20then%20an%20annotation%20of%20type%20T%20may%20be%20written%20as%20a%20modifier%20for%20any%20declaration.)".

So given this in Java 19:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface A {}

public class B<@A C> {}
```

…I would think it would be legal:

- `C` is a type parameter declaration so
- `@A`, which is `@Target`-less, should be able to apply to it, and
- this is not (seemingly) a type context listed in the [Java Language Specification version 19 section 4.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.11).

But `javac` says that `@A` is `not applicable in this type context`.

Is this a bug?  Or have I misread the Java Language Specification, version 19?

Comment: Wait, you're attaching an annotation to a generic type?  Why would one *want* to do that, let alone if it's legal??

Comment: I am a curious fellow.

Comment: I think you should be asking on the relevant OpenJDK mailing list.

Comment: Sure. I like to do my homework first. Anyway see https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/compiler-dev/2023-March/022408.html and following.

Comment: @Makoto You can get the type variables at run-time (e.g., [from a class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getTypeParameters())). And `TypeVariable` is an `AnnotatedType`. So, one might want to define behavior at run-time based on an annotation on the type parameter. Not sure if they're directly processed (via an annotation processor) at compile-time though.

Comment: Indeed they are available at compile-time in an annotation processor, at least in Java 11+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change to make `@Target`-less annotations "applicable in all declaration contexts" happened in [JDK-8261610](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8261610).

I agree with your reading of [JLS 19 §9.6.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.1), which says that the 'declaration contexts' include
"type parameter declarations of generic classes, interfaces, methods, and constructors", and that

> If an annotation of type `java.lang.annotation.Target` is not present on the declaration of an annotation interface `A`, then `A` is applicable in all declaration contexts and in no type contexts.

I think this is a bug: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8303784

Comment: Perfect; +1 for the JDK bug references.

Comment: @LairdNelson - Note who created the bug and when it was created :-)

Comment: Ha; sure; I meant in particular JDK-8261610

Comment: Thanks for the PR, too: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/12914